# Django filtering and deleting

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I have this modelViewSet

```
class LikeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Likes.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LikeSerializer
    filter_fields = ('user','post')

    def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
        post = Likes.objects.get(pk=pk)
        post.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

I'm trying to filter using the url such as:

```
http://localhost:8000/likes/?user=anon&post=1
```

And then delete that specific result that I get from django but django keeps on giving me

```
delete() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)
```

I can't really figure out why. Can anyone help please? Thanks! I'm using Django Rest Framework

EDIT: This is the model for the LikeViewSet:

```
class Likes(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name='liker')
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='   post' )
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)
```

The idea is, it's a model table for a relationship between a user model and a post model so the filtering has to be done in the url that way

Answer (score 0):

When you're using a `ViewSet`, you should use the `destroy()` method rather than `delete()`.

See documentation [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets):

> A ViewSet class is simply a type of class-based View, that does not
>   provide any method handlers such as .get() or .post(), and instead
>   provides actions such as .list() and .create().

Based on your code, it doesn't look like you're doing anything unique in the `destroy/delete` method. Are you fine with just using the default `destroy` function?

Comment: Does destroy use the same delete http request?

Comment: @JohnD Yep. There's a chart of how the HTTP verbs match up with the view set methods [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers#simplerouter).

Comment: How will I do it with filtering too? Sorry, I'm new to this :/

Comment: @JohnD No problem. How are you using your filters? Hard to say, but the query parameters may be unnecessary. Is the `post` you're passing just a `pk`? If so, that's something that will be implemented automatically by the `ModelViewSet` and `Router`. Basically, the url `localhost:8000/likes/1` will give you the proper result (based on your HTTP verb) for the model with a `pk` of 1. For accessing the username, it may be better to get it in your `view`--`user = self.request.user`. Docs on different ways to filter are [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering#filtering).

Comment: I edited the question to show the model. I've tried these but I'm trying to figure out if I could do something like change the queryset of the destroy() method like: Likes.objects.filter(user = user, post = post) user and post being the attributes being filtered through the url